# How to display data from db to view in Laravel 8.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I would like to return data from db to view. It works perfectly when I'm trying to get data from main table, but whenever I'm trying to take data from other table which got foreign key in that table, it comes back with error

```
Attempt to read property "name" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel1\resources\views\frontend\object.blade.php)
```

**FrontendController**

```
 public function object($id)
    {
        $object = $this->fR->getObject($id);
        //dd($objects);
        return view('frontend.object',['object'=>$object]);
    }
```

**FrontendRepository**

```
public function getObject($id)
    {
        return EventObject::find($id);
        return EventObject::with(['clubs'])->get();
    }
```

**EventObject Model(which actually works for main table only)**

```
class EventObject extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';
/*
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City');
    }
    */

    public function clubs()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Club');
    }
}
```

**Club Model**

```
class Club extends Model
{
    protected $table= 'clubs';


    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City');
    }
}
```

**object.blade view in which I'm trying to display data**

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid places">


    <h1 class="text-center">{{ $object->name }} event name <small>city name</small></h1>
    <h3 class="text-center"> {{$object->clubs->name}}club name</h3>

    <p>{{$object->content}}</p>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You r returning twice in your `getObject` method that is why its not reaching the second statement . It should be like this

```
public function getObject($id)
{
    return EventObject::with(['clubs'])->find($id); //better use findOrfail($id)
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading